# oidc-provider - How to delete cookies generated at interaction login using oidc-provider

Tags: node-oidc-provider

The problem that is being replicated, is when sew renders the login page, then we proceed to perform the authentication, now redirects us to the dashboard of the site, at this point we proceed to close the session and again these cookies that were generated in the previous interaction, were not deleted.
This problem is repetitive and is generated over and over again.
I attach the library we are using and its version is the "oidc-provider": "^7.11.5"
https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PStEa.jpg)

The expected behavior is to delete the cookie once authenticated and redirected to the dashboard page.